# Cannot host create-react-app build on shared server, getting 404 errors related to chunk.js file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server, build

I am using **create-react-app**. Everything works until I go to create a build.

I run:

```
npm run build
```

The build is created. I then download the build file and upload to a shared server via cPanel.

When I go to load the website I get the following errors in browser console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.a060bf3c.chunk.css:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
main.b69fe908.chunk.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
(index):1 GET my_url/static/css/main.a060bf3c.chunk.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
(index):1 GET my_url/static/js/2.57e02e7f.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
(index):1 GET my_url/static/js/main.b69fe908.chunk.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
manifest.json:1 GET my_url/manifest.json 404
manifest.json:1 Manifest: Line: 1, column: 1, Syntax error.
```

I also added my_url to the package.json:

```
{
    "homepage" : my_url
}
```

I had this problem before, when I was using FTP to transfer the build directory to the shared server.

It seemed that Filezilla was cutting off the large chunk.js file. However using cPanel did work, although now it is not. Do I need to somehow compress the chunk.js file futher. This is not a large application.

Answer (score 0):

Are the files presents on the ftp (even if uncut)?

- main.a060bf3c.chunk.css
- 2.57e02e7f.chunk.js
- main.b69fe908.chunk.js
- manifest.json

If they are not presents, well you just have a ftp connection problem.

If they are presents, you just have to check the static file server configuration, it probably does not check under the good directory.